# Customer Comment box during checkout

Tags: checkout, extensions

Does anyone know of any way to add a section on the checkout page where a customer can leave a comment/instructions that can be tied to their order?

Comment: The stubs are in the Magento code to do this, I used the Whitepixels module posted on the Magento forums to get it working. http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewreply/276995/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use [Magemaven Order Comment](https://github.com/magemaven/magento-order-comment) for this.

Comment: Thanks @Fooman I am a big fan of your extensions! I actually installed the Magemaven Order comment extension you recommended and I'm wondering if you could recommend how to use this with one of your extensions. Specifically, "Fooman Email Attachments" which we are mainly using for the "Print Order Confirmation" functionality. I'm wondering how I could get the comments left by the user to show up on the Order Confirmations we print. Thanks

Comment: Something like this             $page->drawText(Mage::helper('ordercomment')->escapeHtml($order->getCustomerComment()), 35, $this->y, 'UTF-8'); $this->y -=15; added to /app/code/community/Fooman/EmailAttachments/Model/Order/Pdf/Order.php should get you close. As a sidenote our Pdf Customiser extension supports comments by the Magemaven extension out of the box.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Are you saying it supports the extension out of the box for even for the PDF prints?

Comment: EmailAttachments does not offer support out of the box - see the code change above. For Pdf Customiser support is included and no code edits are required.

Comment: thanks. I just want to clarify that we're speaking of the same thing. When I go under Sales>Orders> and I bring up an order I get a "Print" button, compliments of your extension :). When I print this out I am not seeing the comments left by the customer. I'm not sure if the PDF that I get when I hit the "Print" button is the same as what is attached to an email.

Comment: The pdf created by the print button is the same that would be attached to the order confirmation email (if enabled). For the order comment to appear you would need to add the code I have posted a few comments earlier.

Comment: Thanks so much! Does it matter where in the Order.php I add this?

Comment: Also you mentioned that the PDF customizer would do this without any additional editing? Can you confirm this is the correct extension http://store.fooman.co.nz/extensions/magento-extension-pdf-customiser.html

Comment: The link above is correct. For editing the Order.php you can add this anywhere between line 70 and line 139 depending on where you want to show it.

Comment: thanks! I did try and add the following code to order.php:

$page->drawText(Mage::helper('ordercomment')->escapeHtml($order->getCustomerComm‌​ent()), 35, $this->y, 'UTF-8'); $this->y -=15;

but had no luck with seeing any comments when I did some testing. Is there a step I am missing?

Comment: Link doesnt work anymore. Is it this one https://github.com/magemaven/magento-order-comment?

Comment: @sv3n yes it is - updated the answer as well.